# IntentDialog is not in BotFramework SDK4, so how to recognized intent when NLP is Google dialogflow

Tags: botframework

I am using `Botframework SDK v4` and NLP is as google dialogflow. I need to find intent and it's fulfillment text through recognnizer.  The below given code works in SDK v3. 
is there any substitue class for `IntentDialog` in SDK v4 ? so that
code will work.

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to use correct code formatting when asking questions. Your question has unformatted code and is so clumsy to read(downvote for that. Edit it to get upvote)

Comment: Corrected changes as mentioned

Comment: That's wrong code formatting is different from text formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an equivalent to IntentDialog being developed to be included in a future build. Unfortunately, at this time there is no substitution.